# Best way to secure a WCF service when used from an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have a multilayer asp.net mvc application consisting of the following levels:

- Database (with stored procedures, views and tables)
- WCF service (containing business logic and connection to the database through Entity Framework)
- Asp.net mvc application communicating with the WCF service and generating html
- Browser

The end-users are authenticated in the asp.net mvc layer using Identity 2.0.

The web server is the only client for the WCF service.

Are there any best-practices for this scenario?

The web server and the WCF service might be running in different locations so we cannot use the intranet protocols.

Since we control both the web server and the WCF service we know that the communication will be point-to-point. This means we can use transport security to avoid the extra overhead with message security.

According to this, [Improving Web Services Security: Scenarios and Implementation Guidance for WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx#TransportSecurityWCF), there are two choices for transport security over internet:

- Basic authentication with basicHttpBinding
- Certificate authentication with wsHttpBinding

Which one would be best suited to this scenario where there basically is only one client for the WCF service?

Due to the stateless nature of http for each new request to the web server a new service-proxy is instantiated.

Is there a way to cache the authentication info from the WCF service on the calling web server to better performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up certificate authentication between your WCF and MVC servers using BasicHTTPBinding ... I've done it. But I'm not sure why you use BasicHTTPBinding when, from your description, all the backend services (WCF and MVC) are Microsoft based.

BasicHTTPBinding is a generic WCF protocol that will accept any properly formatted HTTP request (Gets/Post), whether the request comes from a Windows machine or the JAVA/PHP world. It's also, as you say, stateless. That makes BasicHTTPBinding good for interop situations, but more complex (than say wsHTTPBinding) when setting communication between two MS-centric systems.

By default, for instance, NONE is the default encryption for BasicHttpBinding. Adding Transport takes programming and lot of trial and error to get running, from my experience. BasicHttpBinding, also, doesn't support transactions or sessions while WSHttpBinding does. So, based on your description, WSHttpBinding will be simpler and easier to setup and maintain in the long run. But you might also consider NetTCPBinding since you're going server-to-server.

Below you'll find a great MS site explaining all the different WCF protocols, including to pros and cons of each approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx